# Order by conditions on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have products that have prices with a determinate start date and a finish date. I want to make a query on Active Record to capture all products with a start date less than the current date but I want to order them to the products with finish date less than the current date stay on the final of my result.

In other words, I want that this query bellow returns all products with start_date less than the current date, but I want the result to be ordered by name and products with finish date less than the current date stay always on final of the result.

`Products.joins(:prices).where('prices.start_date <= ?', Time.current).order(:name)`

I use rails 4 here.

Someone can help?

Comment: Your last line which says **ordered by name and products with finish date less than the current date stay always on final of the result.** is quite confusing. Can you give example with some product and price record ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```rb
Products.joins(:prices).where('prices.start_date <= ?', Time.current).order(:name).order('prices.finish_date DESC')
```